# "Unable to load Java Runtime Environment" when starting SQLWorkbench/J

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, sql-workbench-j

I get `Unable to load Java Runtime Environment` when starting [SQLWorkbenchJ.app](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/).

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.2, and I installed the app with `brew cask install sqlworkbenchj`. My JDK 8 is installed using `brew install adoptopenjdk8`.

How do I solve this problem?  SQLWorkbench/J does not provide any other helpful messages, even when I start it with `open -a` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Luckily I found a hint on [SQLWorkbench/J's forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sql-workbench/cQN_epMyM1M/V-J0kksuCwAJ)

The fix was to add ...

```
<key>JVMRuntime</key>
<string>adoptopenjdk-8.jdk</string>
```

... to `/Applications/SQLWorkbenchJ.app/Contents/Info.plist`, and create a symlink to JDK8:

```
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk /Applications/SQLWorkbenchJ.app/Contents/PlugIns/
```

Voila!

Comment: There is also the "java -jar /Applications/SQLWorkbenchJ.app/Contents/Java/sqlworkbench.jar </dev/null &>/dev/null &" option in the same forum: https://groups.google.com/g/sql-workbench/c/cQN_epMyM1M/m/W759i5zxAgAJ

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Big Sur and openjdk.jdk.

Comment: I had the same problem with JDiskReport and fixed it with your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Provided solution worked also for [ExecuteQuery.app](http://executequery.org) Thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me after installing SQLWB from brew.  What did work was installing from https://www.sql-workbench.eu/downloads.html