# Unable to run SQLWorkbenchJ on Mac OS with `temurin-18.jdk` or `sapmachine-jdk-11.0.11.jdk`: Unable to load Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, sql-workbench-j, java-runtime-compiler, eclipse-temurin

[Related to this post, but I do not have enough reputation to post a comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006031/unable-to-load-java-runtime-environment-when-starting-sqlworkbench-j).

## The problem: SQL Workbench J fails to use Java on my machine.

Steps I took:

1. Installed SQLWorkbenchJ with `brew install --cask sqlworkbenchj`
2. Tried to launch SQL Workbench J, but was not a trusted app
3. Went to system preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General then opted to launch SQL Workbench J
4. Tried again to launch SQL Workbench J, but got error unable to load `Java Runtime environment.`
5. Followed instructions in link above. Explicitly:

- Opened `Applications/SQLWORKbenchJ.app/Contents/Info.plist` in a text editor
- Added this code to the file, just before the `<key>JVMArguments</key>` code:

```
<key>JVMRuntime</key>
<string>temurin-18.jdk</string>
```

- Saved the file
- Created a simlink by running in a terminal: `ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-18.jdk /Applications/SQLWorkbenchJ.app/Contents/PlugIns/`

6. Tried again to launch SQL Workbench J, but still got error unable to load `Java Runtime environment.`

I also tried using `sapmachine-jdk-11.0.11.jdk` in the `Info.plist` file and the symlink, but also hit the error.

I have *not* tried other `jdk`s, and am open to try, if given some instructions on which to use and how. :)

## Expected result: SQLWorkbenchJ should launch without these java runtime errors

Comment: I can confirm that this method _does_ work for `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk`, but not for `adoptopenjdk-11.jdk`.